# Swagger UI try action method does not replace route parameters, it sends the placeholder "{paramName}" instead

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

**Using ASP.Net Core 3.1 with NSwag.AspNetCore v13.7.0 from NuGet**

I have this action method

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion(EosApiVersion.CurrentVersion)]
[Route(EosApiConsts.BaseRoute + "/[Controller]")]
public class PartyController : ControllerBase
{       

    [HttpGet("{identityNumber}", Name = nameof(GetPersonById))]
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(DefaultApiConventions), nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Get))]
    public ActionResult<PersonResource> GetPersonById([FromQuery] GetPersonInput input)
    {
      //code omitted for brevity
    }

 }
```

And GetPersonInput is:

```
public class GetPersonInput
{
        [FromQuery]
        public IdentityType? IdentityType { get; set; }

        [FromRoute]
        public string IdentityNumber { get; set; }
}
```

When I invoke it from Postman it works fine. But when I invoke it from Swagger UI, who identify the method signature well, it passes `/{IdentityNumber}` to the URI instead of the number I entered in the UI:

The actual call is (from Postman):
https://localhost:44343/api/person/25062140?identityType=DU

but swagger UI builds this curl:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:44343/api/person/{identityNumber}?identityType=DU" -H "accept: application/json"
```

which produces this request:

```
https://localhost:44343/api/person/{identityNumber}?identityType=DU
```

which lead to an exception:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Here is my Startup configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    //Add routing 
    services.AddRouting(options =>
    {
        options.LowercaseUrls = true;
    });

    services.AddControllers();
    //services.AddControllers().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2); //The problem also happens with CompatiblityVersion set to 2.2

    //Add OpenApi
    services.AddOpenApiDocument();

    services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0, status: "dev");
            options.ApiVersionReader = new QueryStringApiVersionReader();
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            options.ReportApiVersions = true;
            options.ApiVersionSelector = new CurrentImplementationApiVersionSelector(options);
        });
    }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    //Use OpenApi with UIs
    app.UseOpenApi();
    app.UseSwaggerUi3();
    //app.UseReDoc();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually it's very simple, the route parameter is case senstive. Just change `{identityNumber}` to `{IdentityNumber}`:

```
[HttpGet("{IdentityNumber}", Name = nameof(GetPersonById))]
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof(DefaultApiConventions), nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Get))]
public ActionResult<PersonResource> GetPersonById([FromQuery] GetPersonInput input)
{
  //code omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: that's true! It works. But I want to keep camelCase in route parameters. How to do it?

Comment: @Lupa You can keep camelCase in route parameters - the requirement for Swagger "Try It Out" to work properly is to ensure that the HttpGet attribute parameter name *matches* the property name in your GetPersonInput class - including the *case* - so to keep camelCase, change the property "IdentityNumber" to "identityNumber" in the GetPersonInput class.